# Speed up Excel VBA search script

Tags: vba, excel, search

I need to search for duplicate values and mark them in an Excel spreadsheet. I have my data to verify in column `D` and the data where possible duplicates are in column `K`. I need to check for each row in column `D` all the rows in col. `K`.

This is my current script for this:

```
Sub MySub()
Dim ThisCell1 As Range
Dim ThisCell2 As Range
    For Each ThisCell1 In Range("D1:D40000")
    'This is the range of cells to check
        For Each ThisCell2 In Range("K1:K40000")
        'This is the range of cells to compare
            If ThisCell1.Value = ThisCell2.Value Then
            If ThisCell1.Value <> "" Then
                ThisCell1.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
                Exit For
                End If
            Next ThisCell2
        Next ThisCell1
End Sub
```

The problem with this is that it's *VERY* slow. I mean it takes *hours* to check the data which is not acceptable. Even when the range is set to `1:5000`, it still takes 10-15 minutes to finish. Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: How do you define your search? Are you checking if a value in Column D appears in Column K? Or does it have to appear in Column K more than once?

Comment: I'm checking if a value in column `K` appears in column `D`. There can be multiple occurences in column `D`, so that's why the search has to check all the rows in `K` for each row in `D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary will be the fastest way to achieve what you are looking for.  Don't forget to add a reference to the 'microsoft scripting runtime' in your project

```
Sub MySubFast()
    Dim v1 As Variant
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim c As Range

    v1 = Range("D1:D40000").Value
    For Each c In Range("K1:K40000")
        If Not dict.Exists(c.Value) Then
            dict.Add c.Value, c
        End If
    Next

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(v1, 1) To UBound(v1, 1)
        If v1(i, 1) <> "" Then
            If dict.Exists(v1(i, 1)) Then
                Range("D" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

note : this is an improvement of @Jeanno answer.

Comment: My script with 13k rows in column D and 4.5k in column K took more than 2 hours to complete. Your version took 6 minutes :))

Answer (score 1):

Use arrays instead of referencing objects (Ranges) way faster.

```
Sub MySubFast()
    Dim v1 As Variant
    Dim v2 As Variant
    v1 = Range("D1:D40000").Value
    v2 = Range("K1:K40000").Value
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = LBound(v1, 1) To UBound(v1, 1)
        For j = LBound(v2, 1) To UBound(v2, 1)
            If v1(i, 1) = v2(j, 1) Then
                If v1(i, 1) <> "" Then
                    Range("D" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you just highlighting cells in column D if the value exists in column K? No need for VBA for this, just use conditional formatting.

- Select column D (selecting the whole column is fine)
- Add a conditional format using this formula: `=COUNTIF($K:$K,$D1)>0`

The conditional format will apply and update automatically as you change data in columns D and K, and it should be basically instant